# Enable to call unmanaged method - "Unable to find an entry point named 'XXX' in DLL 'XXX.dll'."

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I trying to use a method in a dll written in C in a C# console app project.
this is the method signature in h file I got :

```
DLL_PUBLIC sint AshrAPI_TranRecToRefunISO(char* TranRec , byte* RefunISO , usint* ISOLength);
```

I used P/Invoker to create the corresponding method in C#:

```
[DllImport(@"Ashrait.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I2)]
        internal static extern short AshrAPI_TranRecToRefunISO([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string TranRec, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] RefunISO, ushort ISOLength);
```

but no matter which UnmanagedType I try to use, I always get the same exception :
Unable to find an entry point named 'XXX' in DLL 'XXX.dll

can anyone see something wrong ?

Comment: The type of the last argument is wrong `ushort` is not a pointer type. However, that's probably not the cause of your problem.

Comment: It just means there's no dll export exactly named "AshrAPI_TranRecToRefunISO" to your "ashrait.dll" wherever that file is found. Make sure you're looking at the expected "ashrait.dll", and then use a tool such as Windows SDK's dumpbin to determine what's really exported (dumpbin /exports ashrait.dll) or https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies

Comment: If it can't find the entrypoint then it doesn't exist. Possibly the C++ compiler has mangled the function name, because it wasn't declared `extern`. Side point: the parameters should be `[In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string TranRec, [Out] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 2)] byte[] RefunISO, out ushort ISOLength`

Comment: I used dumpbin /exports ashrait.dll to list the methods exposed in dll , and i can see the method I'm trying to call:
ordinal   hint    RVA                name
 155       9A     000360C0 AshrAPI_TranRecToRefunISO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so found out the issue! since I loaded the dll to project as an item and not as a reference, I've put it in resources folder inside the project.
once I moved the dll to root project folder everything started working :)